# How set the font size on all android alert dialogs, from phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, android-alertdialog, font-size

I'm having some difficulty with Android. Recently I created an app in Phonegap, and launched it on the devices. It works, but on low resolutions the alert dialog text becomes on two rows.
And i would like to remove that, I tried searching on google, and all I could found was setting the textview on java. My project doesn't have 1 line of java code. So my question is this: How do I set the font size of **ALL** alert dialogs on android from the xml. Keep in mid that I've already tried from the css, android manifest.